# How to save XML file as .xml which is output from SQL Server in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server

I want to run SQL query in Java and the result of the query is in xml. The query result is as follows -

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Rows>
  <Unique_id>6124</Unique_id>
  <DoorNo>12</DoorNo>
  <StreetNo>1</StreetNo>
  <SiteNo>84904</SiteNo>
</Rows>
<Rows>
  <Unique_id>6125</Unique_id>
  <DoorNo>12</DoorNo>
  <StreetNo>2</StreetNo>
  <SiteNo>84904</SiteNo>
</Rows>
</Root>
```

Now I want to export the above xml into an external file called QueryResult.xml using java.
I have tried using the below java script but unable to save the file.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");   
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://sqldatabase:1009;
databaseName=DatabaseName;user=UserName;password=1234");
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(QueryName);  
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
SQLXML xmlVal1= rs.getSQLXML(1);
String val = xmlVal1.getString();
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("Output.xml"))) {
    out.println(val);
}
```

Query Name:

```
  select Distinct Unique_id, DoorNo, StreetNo, Siteno from Table Name where 
  Unqiue_id IN ( '6124','6125') FOR XML RAW ('Rows'), ROOT ('Root'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLXML xmlVal= rs.getSQLXML(1);
String val = xmlVal.getString();
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("out.xml")) {
    out.println(val);
}
```

### [Here is the Oracle Tutorial with code examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlxml.html).

Regarding your code, 
1. you forgot to make next() on result set;
2. you don't need SQLXML here at all.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");   
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://sqldatabase:1009;
databaseName=DatabaseName;user=UserName;password=1234");
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(QueryName);  
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();
String val = rs.getString(1);
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("Output.xml"))) {
    out.println(val);
}
```